# How to make searchable "text/contents" on wiki page?

Tags: search, search-engine, wiki, meta-tags, wikipedia

I have created a page on Wiki and I want to make the contents of this page searchable via wiki search option.

Wiki mean Wikipedia

i.e. title/heading of page is "ABCDEFG". If someone search "ABCD" in wiki search then this page should appear in search list.

May be its possible through adding  tags into wiki page, but I don't know how to add meta tags in wiki. Or someone know some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very vague: what wiki? Using what search engine?

Comment: Hi @MaxSem: I have edited my question description.  

is it clear now ? What I need to do if I want to make searchable my own created pages on http://www.wikipedia.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in the page (both title and content) will be searched, so when your page contains the word it will be found.

You could force the find by creating a redirect from ABCD to ABCDEFG, altough it that is useless when the redirect title is the first part of the actual title - people will find that with the search autocompletion/suggestion.

Note that the indexing of newly created pages can take its time, especially on large wikis like Wikipedia. Your page might not be found instantly after you saved it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be found this way, the page has to contain ABCD in its title or content. Of course users will find it if they search for ABCD*, but in practice nobody does this.

Answer (score 1):

The following page helps me a lot to solve my issue.

http://www.imagwiki.nibib.nih.gov/mediawiki/index.php?title=Creating_a_New_Wiki_Page

Comment: Really? I can't see any relation to the OP's question. Btw, the official help page is http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Starting_a_new_page

Comment: @Bergi: Thank you. Are you sure this one is official help page?

Comment: Yes, mediawiki.org is the project homepage. I'm not sure what IMAG is or has to do with the MediaWiki software or the Wikipedia project.